# Append/Prepend/AppendTo not Working

Tags: jquery, append, prepend

I'm trying to create a workaround to disable all autofills on my website forms. I've been reading articles and I came across **[here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c41)**. One workaround is to add another input with attribute `autocomplete="address-level4"` to every form so I added the following in my code:

**1.**

```
jQuery("form").prepend('<div style="border:1px solid red;" class="wow"><input type="text" id="PreventChromeAutocomplete" name="PreventChromeAutocomplete" autocomplete="address-level4" /></div>');
```

**2.**

```
jQuery("form").append('<div style="border:1px solid red;" class="wow"><input type="text" id="PreventChromeAutocomplete" name="PreventChromeAutocomplete" autocomplete="address-level4" /></div>');
```

**3.**

```
jQuery('<div style="border:1px solid red;" class="wow"><input type="text" id="PreventChromeAutocomplete" name="PreventChromeAutocomplete" autocomplete="address-level4" /></div>').appendTo('form');
```

Nothing works. There are some forms that have no ID, just name, so I decided to just use `form` What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

-Eli

Comment: Can you share a working fiddle for the issue?

Comment: @DanPhilip I'm not sure if it will replicate the issue. But here's one form: http://dfp-dev.creativequoin.com/checkout/. It has a border style so I should see that at least if it really works.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console. Check if the div is present when you inspect the form.

Comment: @DanPhilip now it's showing but it's purpose is not working. Thanks anyway. :)